# Simple form not sending data via _POST

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

Wow, so this is embarrassing. This is just supposed to be another boring web form. I have done plenty before, but for some reason this specific one doesn't want to cooperate. Am I somehow missing something? I have been trying to figure this out for hours. I swear I have tried troubleshooting everything, without any luck.

Basically, I am attempting to send via $_POST to a PHP file. Eventually I will use AJAX, but right now I can't even get the stupid thing to POST. So when you click submit, it goes to the correct page. But i get an error "Undefined Index (then points to the line that I call my $_POST variable). I have commented out everything on the PHP side (signup1.php) so that now all it does is `var_dump($_POST);` so I can see the data and it isnt getting anything from _POST, the stupid thing is empty. I really think the problem is on the HTML side. I will post my code exactly. It has a ton of extra divs for styling and layout purposes. I am going to keep all of that in there just in case that is the cause of the error, maybe one of you will know. Also, you may notice I am using bootstrap. Maybe that is something? I have used bootstrap for forms before and its worked, but who knows.

```
<form action="actions/signup1.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Smith">
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of name input column -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="801-321-9876">
                </div> 
            </div> <!-- end of phone number input column -->
        </div> <!-- end of first .row of inputs -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 column-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="johnsmith@me.com">
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of email address input column -->

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <select id="city" class="form-control">
                        <option>Las Vegas</option>
                        <option>Salt Lake City</option>
                        <option>I'll Choose a Default Later...</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of city dropdown -->

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="type-of-phone">Type of Phone:</label>
                    <select id="type-of-phone" class="form-control">
                        <option>iPhone</option>
                        <option>Android</option>
                        <option>Windows Phone</option>
                        <option>Blackberry</option>
                        <option>Other Cellphone</option>
                        <option>Landline</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of Smartphone Question Dropdown -->
        </div> <!-- end of second .row of inputs -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

If anyone has any idea please let me know. I am pulling my hair out. I figured I would be up all night with problems having it querying the database, or messing with the AJAX to make it polished, but instead I can't even get past the form submitting the RAW data! Very frustrating. I hope someone out there can see the issue.

For the record this is my exactmessage after the form redirects to the signup1.php (yes it goes to the right page). On the PHP all i do is a Var_dump of the whole $_POST variable.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

And it shows me this:

```
array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You should be adding the name attribute to the form fields.

For example:

```
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="801-321-9876">
```

Comment: That F$%#ing Worked! Ah thank you. I knew it was going to be something simple like this. I was mixing `name` and `id` up. So you want the `For=""` in the labels to match the `name=` in the input. Then the post must use the `name` for the array.

Got it. Well I will never make that mistake again :) Thanks. It won't let me choose correct answer for another 8 mins. I'll check it off soon. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem mate! Actually the "for" attribute of the label should correspond to the ID of the element you wish to bind it to. See you round and good luck :)

Comment: oh my god! i been pulling my head over this for last two days! i can't belive i let it happen too...sometimes these little things just go unnoticed. Thanks to @jacurtis

Comment: It turns out the submit button as well needs to have a name attribute.

Comment: Ditto. Just spent 3hrs wondering why a form wouldn't post. I'd used "id=code" ... but forgot the "name=code" part !! So thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the name attribute to each input tag and the select tag. That should do.

Answer (score 2):

Try To give name to every field of your input fields and also provide name to submit button. So your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use redacted script:

```
<form action="actions/signup1.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Smith">
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of name input column -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="801-321-9876">
                </div> 
            </div> <!-- end of phone number input column -->
        </div> <!-- end of first .row of inputs -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 column-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="johnsmith@me.com">
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of email address input column -->

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
                        <option>Las Vegas</option>
                        <option>Salt Lake City</option>
                        <option>I'll Choose a Default Later...</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of city dropdown -->

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="type-of-phone">Type of Phone:</label>
                    <select id="type-of-phone" name="type-of-phone" class="form-control">
                        <option>iPhone</option>
                        <option>Android</option>
                        <option>Windows Phone</option>
                        <option>Blackberry</option>
                        <option>Other Cellphone</option>
                        <option>Landline</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of Smartphone Question Dropdown -->
        </div> <!-- end of second .row of inputs -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Output:**

[image]