# HTML form returns null

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have this form :

```
 <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Dosya yükle</strong> <small> </small></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                    <div class="input-group image-preview">
                                        <input id="file" type="file" class="form-control image-preview-filename" >
                                        <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Temizle </button>
                                            <!-- image-preview-input -->
                                            <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> <span class="image-preview-input-title">Tara</span>
                                                <!--<input type="file" name="input-file-preview" />-->
                                                <!-- rename it -->
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-default"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> </span>Yükle</button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

When I submit form, null value is returned to the controller. Why is it null? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple form not sending data via \_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887112/simple-form-not-sending-data-via-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `id` attribute, use `name`:

```
<input id="file" type="file" class="form-control image-preview-filename" >
```

Should be:

```
<input name="file" type="file" class="form-control image-preview-filename" >
```

That is because, `name` is used to specify key in the forms, while `id` specifies id of the object

Answer (score 0):

Your comment seems pretty clear to me, if you do not specify a name for your input, it will not get passed in the request, meaning that your controller will receive null. Just specify a name for each needed input and you will be good.

Also, take a look at [FormHelper](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/) to properly handle your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
View Page  

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionmethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formid" }))
 { 
   <input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="save" id="btnid" />
 }

script file



     $(document).on("click", "#btnid", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var fileOptions = {
                success: res,
                dataType: "json"
            }
            $("#formid").ajaxSubmit(fileOptions);
        });

In Controller

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    }
```