# Simple form with bootstrap not sending data via _POST -

Tags: php, forms

First of all, this is my first question ever on stackoverflow. It's a great place to get answers from other's problems. But this time I couldn't find an answer to mine, so my question below...

I am having exactly the same issue as described in this question:
[Simple form not sending data via _POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887112/simple-form-not-sending-data-via-post)

It's exactly the same problem: even `var_dump($_POST);` shows me this: `array(0) { }` and trying to access the data passed gives me a `Notice: Undefined index`

I have been scratching my head for the last 2 days.

My code:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="test">

    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""><br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5" type="submit" name="save-company-button" id="save-company-button" value="SAVE">

</form>
```

This is the simplest form and it still doesn't work. I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

Content of the view:

```html
<?php 

$siteroot = SITEROOT;

// Metadata
$meta_data_title = "About us";

// Page title
$main_title = "About us";

// Additional CSS to the main CSS (bootstrap.css and custom-style.css)
$other_css = "";

// Javascript
ob_start();
require "viewAboutUs/viewAboutUs-javascript.php";
$javascript = ob_get_clean();

// Breadcrumb
$breadcrumb = "<li class=\"breadcrumb-item\"><a href=\"$siteroot\">Home</a></li>
               <li class=\"breadcrumb-item active\" aria-current=\"page\">About us</li>";

// Main content
ob_start();
require "viewAboutUs/viewAboutUs-content.php";
$main_content = ob_get_clean();

// Javascript at the bottom
$javascript_bottom = "";

// Template file
require "template.php"

?>
```

Content of viewAboutUs-content.php:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="test">

    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""><br><br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5" type="submit" name="save-company-button" id="save-company-button" value="SAVE">

</form>
```

The file `viewAboutUs-javascript.php` is empty.

Content of the controller displayAboutUs.php:

```html
<?php

function displayAboutUs() {
    
        var_dump($_POST);

        echo "Test: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";

    if (isset($_POST["save-company-button"])) {

      echo "Button clicked ! <br>";

    }

    require VIEWS_FOLDER . "/pages/viewAboutUs.php";
} 

?>
```

Sorry for the time to provide the code, I am discovering the interface of stackoverflow...

**EDIT #1**

If I copy-paste the items in a simple php file that I put in my /public/ folder, it works without any problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

        var_dump($_POST);

        echo "Test: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";


        if (isset($_POST["save-company-button"])) {

            echo "Button clicked ! <br>";

        }
            

    ?>

    <form action="" method="POST" id="test">

        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5"  name="save-company-button" id="save-company-button" value="SAVE">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The only thing that changes in this case is that I am using bootstrap this time. Otherwise, all my forms would work perfectly the way my code has been organised so far.

**EDIT #2**

After reviewing my code multiple times, the only conclusion I come to is that the issue must be located at the HTML code of the form itself. Something might be missing in the attributes of the form tag and/or one of the input tags, because the current attributes left are the bare minimum.

If somebody is a HTML5 expert, that might be useful...

**EDIT #3**

Things seem to indicate that what I write in my EDIT #2 are correct, because if I do a `var_dump($_POST);` in the main controller (index.php), just before `displayAboutUs()` is called, the results are the same: no data passed.

So, this form is not sending anything so far the way it is when I click on the submit button, but it does if I copy-paste it in another separate test file.

The question is: why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using bootstrap. It might be important.

Comment: Ok, so can you **show us All** the contents of this file

Comment: are you storing the value of `email` in a variable?

Comment: You are posting to the same file meaning that (presumably) at some point there's code in this same file that handles the posted data. Can you share that bit too?

Comment: Sorry, I am discovering the way stack works and I might make some mistakes...

Comment: The HTML posted in my original question is located in a view file. The data passed to a controller with then handles it. I just tried to display it by doing: echo "Test: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";

Comment: @ Fareed Khan - No, just doing this: echo "Test: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";

Comment: @ RiggsFolly - I updated the original post. It has always worked with this structure on other projects, but since I used bootstrap this time, the issue of forms not working has appeared only now.

Comment: @ apokryfos - The handling of the content of the form is done by displayAboutUs().

Answer (score 0):

After burning my brain and getting close to throwing my computer through the window, I finally got it. So I put the solution here so that other people can learn from my mistake.

The problem was coming from my .htaccess file, which was missing (I had copied-pasted the structure of a previous project as a template for my new one) and, as hidden files were not displayed, I of course missed the .htaccess when manually copying the files...

Here is the missing content that was causing so much trouble:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

So, as a reminder for myself and others, if something even dead simple is desperately not going right, check what you can't see ;-)

Hope this helps! And thanks for those who tried to help.

This question can be closed, but I can't see how to proceed...